# Auth0 OWIN API not validating JWT token when published via Docker Container on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, owin, auth0

My OWIN Web.API 2 Hosted on EC2 will not authorize a JWT token.  I have tested the functionality locally with out a problem but once I publish it out to my docker container hosted on EC2 it responds with a 401.  I am using the default RS256 Algorithm and these settings:

```
var domain = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AUTH0_DOMAIN");
var audience = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AUTH0_CLIENT_IDS");
var keyResolver = new OpenIdConnectSigningKeyResolver(domain);
appBuilder.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
                new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                    AllowedAudiences = new[] { audience },
                    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                    {
                        ValidAudience = audience,
                        ValidIssuer = domain,
                        IssuerSigningKeyResolver = (token, securityToken, identifier, parameters) => keyResolver.GetSigningKey(identifier)
                    }
                });
```

My Endpoint simply states whether your are authenticated or not.

```
[Authorize]
        [Route("secure")]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetSecured()
        {
            var userId = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity.GetUserId();
            return Request.CreateResponse($"Hello, {userId}! You are currently authenticated.");
        }
```

Here is my Startup config:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
        {
            appBuilder.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll); //must be first
            Auth0Config.Register(appBuilder);
            var httpConfiguration = new HttpConfiguration();
            httpConfiguration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            UnityConfig.Register(httpConfiguration);
            appBuilder.UseWebApi(httpConfiguration);
        }
```

Comment: I have had this problem many times in the past and it usually boils down to configuration settings not being correct. Check that the domain is correct (with the trailing '/') as well as your other settings.  Also make sure if you are calling this endpoint from a different domain (Angular SPA, etc.) that you have enabled CORS as well.

Comment: I've made sure I have the trailing slash and I added my startup configuration to my question.

Answer (score 0):

I no longer use the OWIN pipeline but from a previous project here is how I had it configured.  It looks like you are using OpenID, I did not. Not sure if this helps.

```
var issuer = AppSettings.Auth0Domain;
            var audience = AppSettings.Auth0ClientID;
            var secret = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Auth0ClientSecret"]);

            app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
                new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                    AllowedAudiences = new[] {audience},
                    IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[]
                    {
                        new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, secret)
                    },
                    Provider = new Auth0AuthenticationProvider()
                });
```

**EDIT** Added Auth0AuthenticationProvider

```
public class Auth0AuthenticationProvider : IOAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider
{
    private string token;

    public Task ApplyChallenge(OAuthChallengeContext context)
    {
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    public Task RequestToken(OAuthRequestTokenContext context)
    {
        token = context.Token;
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    public Task ValidateIdentity(OAuthValidateIdentityContext context)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);

        var notPadded = token.Split('.')[1];
        var padded = notPadded.PadRight(notPadded.Length + (4 - notPadded.Length % 4) % 4, '=');
        var urlUnescaped = padded.Replace('-', '+').Replace('_', '/');
        var claimsPart = Convert.FromBase64String(urlUnescaped);

        var obj = JObject.Parse(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(claimsPart, 0, claimsPart.Length));

        // simple, not handling specific types, arrays, etc.
        foreach (var prop in obj.Properties().AsJEnumerable())
        {
            switch (prop.Name)
            {
                case "app_metadata":
                    SetAppMetadataClaims(context, prop.Value.ToString());
                    break;
            }
        }

        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    private static void SetAppMetadataClaims(OAuthValidateIdentityContext context, string jsonString)
    {
        var appMetadata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Auth0AppMetaDataModel>(jsonString);

        if(!context.Ticket.Identity.HasClaim("AccountId", appMetadata.accountId.ToString()))
            context.Ticket.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("AccountId", appMetadata.accountId.ToString()));
        if (!context.Ticket.Identity.HasClaim("ClientId", appMetadata.clientId.ToString()))
            context.Ticket.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("ClientId", appMetadata.clientId.ToString()));
        if (!context.Ticket.Identity.HasClaim("IsActive", appMetadata.isActive.ToString()))
            context.Ticket.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("IsActive", appMetadata.isActive.ToString()));

        if (appMetadata.roles == null)
            return;

        foreach (var role in appMetadata.roles)
        {
            if (context.Ticket.Identity.HasClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, role))
                continue;

            context.Ticket.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your Auth0AuthenticationProvider look like?  I'm trying out this with HS256.

Comment: Well, I've tried out switching to RS256 using UseJwtBearerAuthentication and I can debug without any issues but I receive errors on docker compose-up like so:


System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 01000042

I am using mono:onbuild as my image base.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not with Auth0 using HS256 or RS256 but instead with the base image I was using.  Mono was failing silently most likely blocking the validation of my token.  I have switched over to dotnet core in order to use the docker image: microsoft/dotnet:latest

My Startup file now appears like this:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                    builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowCredentials());
            });

            ...
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
            var options = new JwtBearerOptions
            {
                Audience = Configuration["Auth0:ApiIdentifier"],
                Authority = $"https://{Configuration["Auth0:Domain"]}/"
            };
            app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(options);

            ...
        }
```